# using two different disk volumes to store elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, digital-ocean

I run elasticsearch on a digital ocean server and I am short on disk space. So I added a additional volume with 3Gb.

```
/dev/vda1        59G   47G  9.6G  83% /
/dev/sda         100G   0G   100G  0% /mnt/volume2
```

on index in my elasticsearch database is quite large

```
test-index 0     p      STARTED    27240256  83.3gb 127.0.0.1 h3awYIM
```

is it possible to store the elasticsearch data in two volumes?

```
/var/www# curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "WU6cQ-o",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "hKc147QfQqCefLliStLNtw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "5395e21",
    "build_date" : "2016-12-06T12:36:15.409Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.3.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

EDIT:
Following the suggestion by Val below I provided es with a path.data flag like

```
-Epath.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch,/mnt/volume2/es_data
```

this seems to work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely store your index data in multiple storage locations. Simply open your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and modify the [`path.data` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#path-settings) to include all the volumes where you want to store data.

In your case, it should look like this (your paths may vary):

```
path:
  data:
    - /var/data/elasticsearch
    - /mnt/volume2/data/elasticsearch
```

You'll need to restart ES in order for this change to take effect.

Comment: hi val, thanks for your answer... could you have a look at my edits above? thanks carl

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: I added that information above... note the error I currently deal with at the end